# How to access js methods in separate file from html file? Or I did something wrong in js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a project to create a virtual keyboard and all buttons are required to be created in html file.
I am trying to access methods inside js file which are created inside an object and to use them for elements I created in html file.
But, I have issues as I am trying to go through the elements in html file and to make them work.

I'm sure I did something wrong in the JS file

```js
const vkeyboard_keys = document.getElementsByClassName("vkeyboard_keys");
const vkb = new Keyboard(vkeyboard_keys);


this.Keyboard = {
  elements: {
    main: null,
    keysContainer: null,
    keys: []
  },

  eventHandlers: {
    oninput: null,
    onclose: null
  },

  properties: {
    value: "",
    capsLock: true
  },

  init() {

    this.elements.keys = this.elements.keysContainer.querySelectorAll(".vkeyboard_key");

    document.querySelectorAll(".textfield").forEach(element => {
      element.addEventListener("focus", () => {
        this.open(element.value, currentValue => {
          element.value = currentValue;
        });
      });
    });
  },
  _keyboardKeys() {
    switch (id) {
      case "backspace":
        Element.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this.properties.value = this.properties.value.substring(0, this.properties.value.length - 1);
          this._triggerEvent("oninput");
        });

        break;

      case "caps":
        Element.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this._toggleCapsLock();
          keyElement.classList.toggle(this.properties.capsLock);
        });

        break;

      case "enter":
        Element.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this.properties.value += "\n";
          this._triggerEvent("oninput");
        });

        break;

      case "space":
        Element.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this.properties.value += " ";
          this._triggerEvent("oninput");
        });

        break;

      case "submit":
        Element.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this.close();
          this._triggerEvent("onclose");
        });

        break;

      default:
        Element.textContent = key.toLowerCase();

        Element.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this.properties.value += this.properties.capsLock ? key.toUpperCase() : key.toLowerCase();
          this._triggerEvent("oninput");
        });

        break;
    }
  },

  _triggerEvent(handlerName) {
    if (typeof this.eventHandlers[handlerName] == "function") {
      this.eventHandlers[handlerName](this.properties.value);
    }
  },

  _toggleCapsLock() {
    this.properties.capsLock = !this.properties.capsLock;

    for (const key of this.elements.keys) {
      if (key.childElementCount === 0) {
        key.textContent = this.properties.capsLock ? key.textContent.toUpperCase() : key.textContent.toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  },

  open(initialValue, oninput, onclose) {
    this.properties.value = initialValue || "";
    this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
    this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
  },

  close() {
    this.properties.value = "";
    this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
    this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
  }
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  Keyboard.init();
});
```

```html
<textarea class="textfield">Text Area</textarea>

<div class="vkeyboard_keys">
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">3</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">4</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">5</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">6</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">7</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">8</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">9</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">0</button>
  <button type="button" id="backspace">Back Space</button>
  <br>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">q</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">w</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">e</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">r</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">t</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">y</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">u</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">i</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">o</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">p</button>
  <button type="button" class="enter">Enter</button>

  <br>

  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">a</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">s</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">d</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">f</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">g</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">h</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">j</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">k</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">l</button>
  <button type="button" class="capsLock">Caps Lock</button>

  <br>

  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">z</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">x</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">c</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">v</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">b</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">n</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">m</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">-</button>
  <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">_</button>
  <button type="button" class="shift">Shift</button>

  <br>

  <button type="button" class="space">Space</button>
  <button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to describe the issues, symptoms, what you expect to happen, what actually happens.

Comment: So you're saying that importing the JS file into the HTML file using the `<script>` tags didn't work?

Comment: When im pressing buttons, those values should be written in textarea, but nothing happens. Its like im not accessing js file, or I did something wrong inside js file.

Comment: I made you a proper snippet. It gives errors. Solve them

Comment: But your question title implies that you aren't able to use imported JS functions from another file?

Comment: @revmatcher sorry, corrected.

Comment: Your Keyboard is not a constructor and you call Keyboard.init() instead of vkb.init() or such. `this.Keyboard` is also weird

Comment: Here is something that works better: https://codepen.io/dcode-software/pen/KYYKxP

Comment: Thank you for pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a much simpler virtual keyboard with a lot less javascript if you build the keyboard via an svg. You should try something like this:

keyboard.js

```
const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.keys')

const findKey = (e, fillColor) => {
    keys.forEach(key => {
        if (e.which == key.dataset.name) {
            key.style.fill = fillColor; 
        }
  });
  }


const keyDown = (e) => findKey(e, "red");
const keyUp = (e) => findKey(e, "#1d1d1d");

document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp);
```

keyboard.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="920" height="314" viewBox="0 0 913 314">
    <!-- viewBox="0 0 913 314" -->
    <defs>
        <style>
            .keys {
                fill: #1d1d1d;
                stroke: #bfbfbf;
            }
            .cls-2 {
                stroke: none;
            }
            .cls-3 {
                fill: none;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g id="" data-name="Group 149" transform="translate(-470 -710)">


        <!-- NUMERIC ROW -->

        <!-- Tilde Key -->
        <g id="tilde__group" class="keys" data-name="192" transform="translate(473 713)">
            <rect id="tilde__key" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="59" height="59" rx="8.5" />
            <text id="tilde__text" x="25" y="25">~</text>
            <text id="tilde__text" x="25" y="45">`</text>
        </g>

        <!-- 1 Key -->
        <g id="1__group" class="keys" data-name="49" transform="translate(536 713)">
            <rect id="1__key" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" stroke-width="2" />
            <text class="1__text" x="26" y="25">!</text>
            <text class="1__text" x="25" y="45">1</text>
        </g>

        <!-- 2 Key -->
        <g id="2__group" class="keys" data-name="50" transform="translate(599 713)">
            <rect id="2__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="2__text" x="22" y="25">@</text>
            <text class="2__text" x="25" y="45">2</text>
        </g>

        <!-- 3 Key -->
        <g id="3__group" class="keys" data-name="51" transform="translate(661 713)">
            <rect id="3__key" width="60" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="3__text" x="25" y="25">#</text>
            <text class="3__text" x="25" y="45">3</text>
        </g>

        <!-- 4 Key -->
        <g id="4__group" class="keys" data-name="52" transform="translate(724 713)">
            <rect id="4__key" width="60" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="4__text" x="25" y="25">$</text>
            <text class="4__text" x="25" y="45">4</text>
        </g>

        <!-- 5 Key -->
        <g id="5__group" class="keys" data-name="53" transform="translate(787 713)">
            <rect id="5__key" width="60" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="5__text" x="23" y="25">%</text>
            <text class="5__text" x="25" y="45">5</text>
        </g>

        <!-- 6 Key -->
        <g id="6__group" class="keys" data-name="54" transform="translate(851 713)">
            <rect id="6__key" width="60" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="6__text" x="25" y="25">^</text>
            <text class="6__text" x="25" y="45">6</text>
        </g>

        <!-- 7 Key -->
        <g id="7__group" class="keys" data-name="55" transform="translate(914 713)">
            <rect id="7__key" width="60" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="7__text" x="23" y="25">&</text>
            <text class="7__text" x="25" y="45">7</text>
        </g>

        <!-- 8 Key -->
        <g id="8__group" class="keys" data-name="56" transform="translate(976 713)">
            <rect id="8__key" width="60" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="8__text" x="23" y="25">*</text>
            <text class="8__text" x="25" y="45">8</text>
        </g>

        <!-- 9 Key -->
        <g id="9__group" class="keys" data-name="57" transform="translate(1039 713)">
            <rect id="9__key" width="60" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="9__text" x="24" y="24">(</text>
            <text class="9__text" x="25" y="45">9</text>
        </g>

        <!-- 0 Key -->
        <g id="0__group" class="keys" data-name="48" transform="translate(1101 713)">
            <rect id="0__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="0__text" x="27" y="25">)</text>
            <text class="0__text" x="25" y="45">0</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Hyphen Key -->
        <g id="hyphen__group" class="keys" data-name="189" transform="translate(1163 713)">
            <rect id="hyphen__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="hyphen__text" x="27" y="25">_</text>
            <text class="hyphen__text" x="28" y="45">-</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Equal Key -->
        <g id="equal__group" class="keys" data-name="187" transform="translate(1225 713)">
            <rect id="equal__key" class="keys" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="equal__text" x="27" y="25">+</text>
            <text class="equal__text" x="27" y="45">=</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Delete Key -->
        <g id="delete__group" class="keys" data-name="8" transform="translate(1287 713)">
            <rect width="97" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="delete__text" x="45" y="45">delete</text>
        </g>

        <!-- TOP ROW -->

        <!-- Tab Key -->
        <g id="tab__group" class="keys" data-name="null" transform="translate(473 776)">
            <rect class="cls-2" width="93" height="58" rx="9" />
            <text class="tab__text" x="10" y="45">tab</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Q Key -->
        <g id="q__group" class="keys" data-name="81" transform="translate(569 776)">
            <rect id="q__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="q__text" x="25" y="35">Q</text>
        </g>

        <!-- W Key -->
        <g id="w__group" class="keys" data-name="87" transform="translate(631 776)">
            <rect id="w__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="w__text" x="25" y="35">W</text>
        </g>

        <!-- E Key -->
        <g id="e__group" class="keys" data-name="69" transform="translate(694 776)">
            <rect id="e__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="e__text" x="25" y="35">E</text>
        </g>

        <!-- R Key -->
        <g id="r__group" class="keys" data-name="82" transform="translate(757 776)">
            <rect id="r__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="r__text" x="25" y="35">R</text>
        </g>

        <!-- T Key -->
        <g id="t__group" class="keys" data-name="84" transform="translate(819 776)">
            <rect id="t__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="t__text" x="25" y="35">T</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Y Key -->
        <g id="y__group" class="keys" data-name="89" transform="translate(882 776)">
            <rect id="y__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="y__text" x="25" y="35">Y</text>
        </g>

        <!-- U Key -->
        <g id="u__group" class="keys" data-name="85" transform="translate(944 776)">
            <rect id="u__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="u__text" x="25" y="35">U</text>
        </g>

        <!-- I Key -->
        <g id="i__group" class="keys" data-name="73" transform="translate(1008 776)">
            <rect id="i__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="i__text" x="25" y="35">I</text>
        </g>

        <!-- O Key -->
        <g id="o__group" class="keys" data-name="79" transform="translate(1071 776)">
            <rect id="o__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="o__text" x="25" y="35">O</text>
        </g>

        <!-- P Key -->
        <g id="p__group" class="keys" data-name="80" transform="translate(1133 776)">
            <rect id="p__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="p__text" x="25" y="35">P</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Left Brace Key -->
        <g id="left_brace__group" class="keys" data-name="219" transform="translate(1197 776)">
            <rect id="left_brace__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="left_brace__text" x="25" y="25">{</text>
            <text class="left_brace__text" x="27" y="45">[</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Right Brace Key -->
        <g id="right_brace__group" class="keys" data-name="221" transform="translate(1259 776)">
            <rect id="right_brace__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="right_brace__text" x="25" y="25">}</text>
            <text class="right_brace__text" x="25" y="45">]</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Forward Slash Key -->
        <g id="forward_slash__group" class="keys" data-name="220" transform="translate(1322 776)">
            <rect id="forward_slash__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="forward_slash__text" x="25" y="25">|</text>
            <text class="forward_slash__text" x="25" y="45">\</text>
        </g>

        <!-- MIDDLE ROW -->

        <!-- Caps Lock Key -->
        <g id="caps_lock__group" class="keys" data-name="20" transform="translate(473 837)">
            <rect class="cls-2" width="106" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="caps_lock__text" x="10" y="45">caps lock</text>
        </g>

        <!-- A Key -->
        <g id="a__group" class="keys" data-name="65" transform="translate(583 837)">
            <rect id="a__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="a__text" x="25" y="35">A</text>
        </g>

        <!-- S Key -->
        <g id="s__group" class="keys" data-name="83" transform="translate(647 837)">
            <rect id="s__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="s__text" x="25" y="35">S</text>
        </g>

        <!-- D Key -->
        <g id="d__group" class="keys" data-name="68" transform="translate(709 837)">
            <rect id="d__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="d__text" x="25" y="35">D</text>
        </g>

        <!-- F Key -->
        <g id="f__group" class="keys" data-name="70" transform="translate(772 837)">
            <rect id="f__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="f__text" x="25" y="35">F</text>
        </g>

        <!-- G Key -->
        <g id="g__group" class="keys" data-name="71" transform="translate(836 837)">
            <rect id="g__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="g__text" x="25" y="35">G</text>
        </g>

        <!-- H Key -->
        <g id="h__group" class="keys" data-name="72" transform="translate(897 837)">
            <rect id="h__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="h__text" x="25" y="35">H</text>
        </g>

        <!-- J Key -->
        <g id="j__group" class="keys" data-name="74" transform="translate(961 837)">
            <rect id="j__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="j__text" x="25" y="35">J</text>
        </g>

        <!-- K Key -->
        <g id="k__group" class="keys" data-name="75" transform="translate(1024 837)">
            <rect id="k__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="k__text" x="25" y="35">K</text>
        </g>

        <!-- L Key -->
        <g id="l__group" class="keys" data-name="76" transform="translate(1086 837)">
            <rect id="l__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="l__text" x="25" y="35">L</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Colon Key -->
        <g id="colon__group" class="keys" data-name="186" transform="translate(1147 837)">
            <rect id="colon__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="colon__text" x="25" y="25">:</text>
            <text class="colon__text" x="25" y="45">;</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Quotation Key -->
        <g id="quotation__group" class="keys" data-name="222" transform="translate(1211 837)">
            <rect id="quotation__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="quotation__text" x="25" y="25">"</text>
            <text class="quotation__text" x="27" y="45">'</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Enter Key -->
        <g id="enter__group" class="keys" data-name="13" transform="translate(1276 837)">
            <rect class="enter__key" width="106" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="enter__text" x="60" y="45">enter</text>
        </g>

        <!-- BOTTOM ROW -->

        <!-- Shift Key -->
        <g id="shift__group" class="keys" data-name="16" transform="translate(473 899)">
            <rect class="shift__key" width="141" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="shift__text" x="10" y="45">shift</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Z Key -->
        <g id="z__group" class="keys" data-name="90" transform="translate(615 899)">
            <rect id="z__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="z__text" x="25" y="35">Z</text>
        </g>

        <!-- X Key -->
        <g id="x__group" class="keys" data-name="88" transform="translate(679 899)">
            <rect id="x__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="x__text" x="25" y="35">X</text>
        </g>

        <!-- C Key -->
        <g id="c__group" class="keys" data-name="67" transform="translate(740 899)">
            <rect id="c__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="c__text" x="25" y="35">C</text>
        </g>

        <!-- V Key -->
        <g id="v__group" class="keys" data-name="86" transform="translate(804 899)">
            <rect id="v__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="v__text" x="25" y="35">V</text>
        </g>

        <!-- B Key -->
        <g id="b__group" class="keys" data-name="66" transform="translate(865 899)">
            <rect id="b__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="b__text" x="25" y="35">B</text>
        </g>

        <!-- N Key -->
        <g id="n__group" class="keys" data-name="78" transform="translate(930 899)">
            <rect id="n__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="n__text" x="25" y="35">N</text>
        </g>

        <!-- M Key -->
        <g id="m__group" class="keys" data-name="77" transform="translate(993 899)">
            <rect id="m__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="m__text" x="25" y="35">M</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Comma Key -->
        <g id="comma__group" class="keys" data-name="188" transform="translate(1054 899)">
            <rect id="comma__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="comma__text" x="25" y="25">&lt;</text>
            <text class="comma__text" x="25" y="45">,</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Period Key -->
        <g id="period__group" class="keys" data-name="190" transform="translate(1117 899)">
            <rect id="period__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="period__text" x="25" y="25">></text>
            <text class="period__text" x="25" y="45">.</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Question_Mark Key -->
        <g id="question_mark__group" class="keys" data-name="191" transform="translate(1179 899)">
            <rect id="question_mark__key" width="60" height="60" rx="8.5" />
            <text class="question_mark__text" x="25" y="25">?</text>
            <text class="question_mark__text" x="25" y="45">/</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Shift2 Key -->
        <g id="shift2__group" class="keys" data-name="16" transform="translate(1243 899)">
            <rect class="shift2__key" width="141" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="shift2__text" x="10" y="45">shift</text>
        </g>

        <!-- SPACEBAR ROW -->

        <!-- Control Key -->
        <g id="control__group" class="keys" data-name="17" transform="translate(473 961)">
            <rect class="control__key" width="124" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="control__text" x="10" y="45">control</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Alt Key -->
        <g id="alt__group" class="keys" data-name="18" transform="translate(601 961)">
            <rect class="alt__key" width="97" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="alt1__text" x="10" y="45">alt</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Space Key -->
        <g id="space__group" class="keys" data-name="32" transform="translate(703 961)">
            <rect class="space__key" width="389" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="space__text" x="10" y="45">space</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Alt2 Key -->
        <g id="alt2__group" class="keys" data-name="18" transform="translate(1095 960)">
            <rect class="alt2__key" width="97" height="60" rx="9" />
            <text class="alt2__text" x="10" y="45">alt</text>
        </g>

        <!-- Empty Key -->
        <g id="empty__group" class="keys" data-name="null" transform="translate(1197 961)">
            <rect class="empty__key" width="186" height="60" rx="9" />
        </g>

        </>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But unfortunately I have to use only html in which I have to create all buttons, css and js.

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to understand how to use OOP in js. refer the below code.

```js
class Keyboard {
  constructor() {
    this.Keyboard = {
      elements: {
        main: null,
        keysContainer: null,
        keys: [],
      },

      eventHandlers: {
        oninput: null,
        onclose: null,
      },

      properties: {
        value: "",
        capsLock: true,
      },
    };
  }

  _keyboardKeys() {
    switch (id) {
      case "backspace":
        Element.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this.properties.value = this.properties.value.substring(
            0,
            this.properties.value.length - 1
          );
          this._triggerEvent("oninput");
        });

        break;

      case "caps":
        Element.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this._toggleCapsLock();
          keyElement.classList.toggle(
            "keyboard__key--active",
            this.properties.capsLock
          );
        });

        break;

      case "enter":
        Element.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this.properties.value += "\n";
          this._triggerEvent("oninput");
        });

        break;

      case "space":
        Element.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this.properties.value += " ";
          this._triggerEvent("oninput");
        });

        break;

      case "submit":
        Element.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this.close();
          this._triggerEvent("onclose");
        });

        break;

      default:
        Element.textContent = key.toLowerCase();

        Element.addEventListener("click", () => {
          this.properties.value += this.properties.capsLock
            ? key.toUpperCase()
            : key.toLowerCase();
          this._triggerEvent("oninput");
        });

        break;
    }
  }

  _triggerEvent(handlerName) {
    if (typeof this.eventHandlers[handlerName] == "function") {
      this.eventHandlers[handlerName](this.properties.value);
    }
  }
  _toggleCapsLock() {
    this.properties.capsLock = !this.properties.capsLock;

    for (const key of this.elements.keys) {
      if (key.childElementCount === 0) {
        key.textContent = this.properties.capsLock
          ? key.textContent.toUpperCase()
          : key.textContent.toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  }

  open(initialValue, oninput, onclose) {
    this.properties.value = initialValue || "";
    this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
    this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
  }

  close() {
    this.properties.value = "";
    this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
    this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
  }

  print() {
    console.log(this.Keyboard);
    alert("check console log");
  }
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const vkeyboard_keys = document.getElementsByClassName("vkeyboard_keys");
  const vkb = new Keyboard(vkeyboard_keys);
  document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    //print keybord
    vkb.print();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea class="textfield">Text Area</textarea>

    <div class="vkeyboard_keys">
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">3</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">6</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">7</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">9</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">0</button>
        <button type="button" id="backspace">Back Space</button>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">q</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">w</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">e</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">r</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">t</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">y</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">u</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">i</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">o</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">p</button>
        <button type="button" class="enter">Enter</button>

        <br>

        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">a</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">s</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">d</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">f</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">g</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">h</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">j</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">k</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">l</button>
        <button type="button" class="capsLock">Caps Lock</button>

        <br>

        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">z</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">x</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">c</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">v</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">b</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">n</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">m</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">-</button>
        <button type="button" class="vkeyboard_key">_</button>
        <button type="button" class="shift">Shift</button>

        <br>

        <button type="button" class="space">Space</button>
        <button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>

    </div>
    </div>
    <button id="myBtn">alert keyboard</button>
    <script src="index.js">

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```